# How to check whether a web page has been rendered completely or not?

Tags: webview, render, document

I am making an iOS app, one page of my app has a webview and multiple views follows. In this page, the webview should auto expand and the height should fit with the content injected dynamically, because i do not want the webview has scroll. Now, i have a problem, i can't post the exact height of doucment.body to the client to set webview's height, because i can't confirm when the whole content has been render into the document.

i have tried to check the height change of document.body，till the height is not changed, i post '0'. The client get the signal i post through `invokeNative('changeHeight', params)`，when it is 0, the client get the document.body height, but in my test, that is not the exact height of the document. Just part of the content shows.

```
    function reportHeight() {
        var preH = document.body.offsetHeight;
        var params = {
            "heigh": preH
        };
        invokeNative('changeHeight', params); //the method i communicate with client

        var timeId = setInterval(function() {
            var height = document.body.offsetHeight;
            if((height - preH) == 0) {
                invokeNative('changeHeight', {"heigh": 0});
                clearInterval(timeId);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    invokeNative('changeHeight', {"heigh": 10});
                }, 500)

                return false;
            }
            var params = {
                "heigh": (height - preH)
            };
            preH = height;
            invokeNative('changeHeight', params);
        }, 30);
    }
```

is there any way to fix this problem?

By the way, the content injected into the page only has css and html tags, and there is no js.

Comment: A question: what do you call that function? Are you using the `window.onload` event?

Comment: @MarcoCI Yes, i use this method into the document body. the whole content of the document is generated through `app.js`, the function above is also into it.

<body>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>